# CssMinimizerPlugin can't parse css template, giving Unknown word error

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, kryzhanovskycssminifier

I am using webpack 5 with MiniCssExtractPlugin, CssMinimizerPlugin plugins. I want to compress my css file, that is actually a template file containing some dynamic css properties like

```
.background {
    <# if(variable == true) {#>
        background: transparent;
    <# }
}
```

When i build my project through web pack I got "Unknown word  error"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I ignore some keyword while compressing css file through webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140731/can-i-ignore-some-keyword-while-compressing-css-file-through-webpack)

Comment: No, It's the same question with different description

Comment: Yes, you stated _the same question_ several times. That's why I voted to close this one, because the other one received more comments.