# Can I ignore some keyword while compressing css file through webpack? In other words I need a loader which just compress my file without validation

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-selectors, compression

I have some programming logic in my css file like

```
.background {
    <# if(variable == true) {>
       background: transparent;
    <# }
 }
```

Can we ignore the <# , if keywords and the webpack let me ignore these keywords and build it without errors.

Comment: Mapping it with my other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140265/cssminimizerplugin-cant-parse-css-template-giving-unknown-word-error

Comment: What do you mean by "update ... in runtime"? Webpack typically does not run at _runtime_, it runs at the stage of _compile-time_ (rather "transpile-time", because JS/CSS aren't _compiled_). If you want a dynamic CSS variable, you could use a CSS custom property. Would have the added benefit of not intermixing your CSS with JS logic.

Comment: I mean to transpile my css file that having some programming logic

Comment: You should find a better way of doing what you want, like with a custom property as Davi suggests